# Vue CLI+Laravel Api request/ response 400 bad request

Tags: php, laravel, vue.js

I am trying to build a application using vue cli and laravel api.
The problem is with getting token response from laravel api.

When I am trying with postman everything is working fine
[image]

But when trying to get token by vue api request via axios/fetch()
[image]

This is code from vue js
[image]

Please some body assist me to solve this.

Answer (score 0):

It's the CORS Issue if you are using laravel 7 you must find a cors.php config file edit it with the URL of the Vue application Don't use `*`
If you are usinga lower version of laravel < 7 make a middleware to handle the CORS but don't allow all origins
`*`

Comment: I am using laravel8, followed your suggession but still having same 400 bad request